# How to override maven Jar with my own Jar in spring boot project?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, maven, continuous-integration

The way my project is setup is that there is a pom.xml

```
 <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
```

And then the dependency is pulled in when maven is run at our CI server:

```
 <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.0.3.RELEASE</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>repackage</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.google.cloud.tools</groupId>
                <artifactId>jib-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.10.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <from>
                        <image>openjdk:11-jdk-slim</image>
                    </from>
                    <container>
                        <ports>
                            <port>8080</port>
                            <port>15370</port>
                        </ports>
                    </container>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.5.1</version> <!-- or newer version -->
                <configuration>
                    <source>11</source> <!-- depending on your project -->
                    <target>11</target> <!-- depending on your project -->
                    <annotationProcessorPaths>
                        <path>
                            <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
                            <artifactId>mapstruct-processor</artifactId>
                            <version>${org.mapstruct.version}</version>
                        </path>
                        <path>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                            <version>${org.projectlombok.version}</version>
                        </path>
                        <!-- other annotation processors -->
                    </annotationProcessorPaths>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </build>
```

But now I want to use my own jar file for springfox-core-3.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar because there's a bug fix I downloaded from the internet that is not merge into that project yet. How do I tell maven to use my jar and not the jar it pulled in?

I searched online and most solutions is telling me to run a maven install command, but I don't run any command line commands at all. The code just gets built by CI by some mvn package command.

Answer (score 0):

You have few options here. The best option would be to have your custom dependency uploaded on maven repository and then your reference inside your pom would work. If you have your own dependency repository (like nexus for example) that could be solution.

You could also do maven install of that custom project on your CI server so that dependency exists locally on build server. But the problem is, if dependency gets deleted from CI server your builds would start to fail.

Now, depending on how big is the fix, you could maybe go for alternative solutions, like [overriding changed classes](https://dzone.com/articles/spring-boot-classloader-and-class-override)

Comment: Thanks thats helpful, apparently it can also be fixed by using a previous version of the jar on the repository. I was shown this https://github.com/pitzcarraldo/springfox-sample/blob/previous/build.gradle on how it was done with gradle, do you know how to do the same for maven?

Comment: What I see from that gradle is that it uses custom repository http://oss.jfrog.org/artifactory/oss-snapshot-local/ for fetching snapshot versions of swagger. To replicate it on maven you should add that repository to your pom.xml file. Here is a link to maven documentation how to do that https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-multiple-repositories.html. After that you need to modify version of swagger library. In that gradle file, version that was referenced is 3.0.0-20190226.020708-23